Bold-Facing a Column and the Pages of Terms in the Glossary
Following this answer, I have adapted my glossary to look like this:

But I would like the left column (the term name) as well as the pages the term is mentioned in to be bold.
Here's my adaptation of @PietervanOostrum's code in that answer:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{p{1cm}p{6cm}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{examp}{
  name        = {Short},%
  description = {Just showing what I mean},%
}

\newglossaryentry{examp2}{
  name        = {A bit longer},%
  description = {asd asd ad das dsd asd asd ads das dasdsa das das dsa das das dsa dsa dsa dsa d as asddas ads dsa das dsa as sda dsa dsa dsa d sa dsa dsa},%
}

\begin{document}
  \glsaddall
  \printglossary[style = mystyle]
\end{document}


Do you use package hyperref?

@Tom Yes, I do use the hyperref package actually. Here's the project.

See the changes in the answer.

If you don't use hyperref package, things will be easier to setup.
There will be three commands that you will need:
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries#1} % For entry name
\renewcommand{\delimR}{$\boldsymbol{-}$} % For range symbol (-) in page list
\renewcommand{\glsnumberformat}[1]{\bfseries#1} % For page number in page list

The second command is needed if you have range of page list. In my opinion, you need to bold the - as well to make the format looks more consistent. e.g., If entries are used in series of continued pages (more than 2), for example page 2, 3 and 4 , the page will be shown as 2-4. So - need to in bold as well, otherwise the format will looks weird in my opinion.
The full example:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{p{1cm}p{6cm}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries#1}
\renewcommand{\delimR}{$\boldsymbol{-}$}
\renewcommand{\glsnumberformat}[1]{\bfseries#1}


\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{examp}{
  name        = {Short},%
  description = {Just showing what I mean},%
}

\newglossaryentry{examp2}{
  name        = {A bit longer},%
  description = {Just showing what I mean, this is a entry with long descriptions which use multiple lines},%
}


\begin{document}
\printglossary[style = mystyle]
\clearpage
\gls{examp2}, \gls{examp}\clearpage
\gls{examp2}, \gls{examp}\clearpage
\gls{examp2}
\end{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
If you use hyperref, these commands is what you need:
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries#1}
\renewcommand{\glswrglosslocationtextfmt}[1]{\bfseries#1}
\renewcommand{\delimR}{$\color{red}\boldsymbol{-}$}
\renewcommand{\delimN}{{\color{red}\bfseries, }}

I use the red color just to show the results obviously. Command \glswrglosslocationtextfmt will set the format only for hyperlinked page number. So the comma will be leave as normal font if you don't redefined the \delimN as bold face.
The full example:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{p{1cm}p{6cm}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\bfseries#1}
\renewcommand{\glswrglosslocationtextfmt}[1]{\bfseries#1}
\renewcommand{\delimR}{$\color{red}\boldsymbol{-}$}
\renewcommand{\delimN}{{\color{red}\bfseries, }}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{examp}{
  name        = {Short},%
  description = {Just showing what I mean},%
}

\newglossaryentry{examp2}{
  name        = {A bit longer},%
  description = {Just showing what I mean, this is a entry with long descriptions which use multiple lines},%
}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style = mystyle]
\clearpage
\gls{examp2}, \gls{examp}\clearpage
\gls{examp2}, \gls{examp}\clearpage
\gls{examp2}
\end{document}



Thank you, @Tom!
